# naudio: how to know which WaveOutEvent raised PlaybackStopped?

Tags: c#, event-handling, naudio

i'm using the example mark posted on his blog about how to play a portion of an audio file:

https://markheath.net/post/naudio-play-extract

i've added a PlaybackStopped EventHandler:

```
player.PlaybackStopped += new EventHandler<StoppedEventArgs>(player_PlaybackStopped);
```

in my application, i sometimes play multiple audio fragments simultaneously; playerA plays "audioA.wav" and playerB plays "audioB.wav".

is there a way in the EventHandler to know which player raised the event? thanks!

Comment: Take a look at the value of `object sender` in your event handler.

Comment: i'm sorry. i should have mentioned that i'd check the sender but didn't see anything usable; i.e. the filename being played. it would be great if the WaveOutEvent constructor accepted a user-settable field (string, int, object, whatever) to tag the object and that field could be picked up in the event handler. i'm a noob so perhaps this is available and i've missed it.